# Coordinate free version of Kerr-Schild perturbation

Tags: differential-geometry, perturbation-theory, general-relativity

For the Kerr-child perturbation, see the Wiki or n-lab.
So far I've seen it only in coordinates. Is there a coordinate free version somewhere?

Comment: Based on quick look at the wikipedia page and the first paragraph of https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.1060, this appears to be a Lorentzian metric of the form $$ g = g_0 + f \theta\otimes\theta, $$ where $g_0$ is the standard flat Minkowski metric, $f$ is a scalar function, and $\theta$ is a $1$-form. Is there something you want to do know beyond this?

Comment: That's a help already. With that in mind, I'll look again at the paper that led to my ? and also the one you recommend.